# Fragment transaction is breaking after cloud Firestore "this" listener

Tags: android, firebase, fragment, google-cloud-firestore, fragmenttransaction

After watching this video by the firestore team : 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDZYIhNkQoM
I have tried to implement the "this" listener before "new" keyword at "OnSuccess"

As an example:

```
 public void pullEventsFromDatabase() {
        mEventRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots) {
                if (documentSnapshots.size() <= 0) {
                    setNothingToShow();
                    Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents. Cat might be empty");
                } else {
                    events.clear();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : documentSnapshots) {
                        Event event = document.toObject(Event.class);
                        events.add(new Event(event.getImageUrl(), event.getTitle(), event.getSummary(), event.getembeddedIDOrPowerLinkID(), event.getLinkToEvent(), event.getLinkToFastReservation(), event.getKey(), event.getDateOfPublish()));
                    }
                    if (events != null) {
                        Collections.sort(events);
                        initEventsRecyclerView();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Instead of "this" I'm using the context which is "getActivity" as this function is executed at onCreateView in a fragment.

Unfortunately while trying to implement this method (only with the context, without it the function works, but it has a bit different effect) The fragment transaction breaks!
Trying to navigate between fragments will work at start but after 2 - 3 times of going through the same fragment will cause the fragment transaction to break completely and stop responding until the app will call onDestroy and onCreate again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does it mean to "completely break"? What are you observing?  When is your function getting called?  What is initEventsRecyclerView() doing?

Comment: @DougStevenson 
"Completely break" means that I have a bottom nav bar and moving between fragments breaks it. 
The function is called on "onCreateview" or "onStart" or "onPause" tried multiple options.
what initEventsRecyclerView() does is initializing the recyclerview by creating a new adapter and filling the adapter with the new array list that it got from the DB.